# What is the best way to keep track of which users are online in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

So I am developing (more playing around with) a realtime game in node.js, I am also using Redis and Sockets.io. I have players create a lobby and join it (kind of like a pre-game chat room, where you can talk to players and select game settings) . The client is written in HTML/CSS/JS, Anyway I want to be able to tell when players disconnect from the lobby, to update the number of players joined on the interface (and joined player names).

Two options I have thought about are:

1. Using redis' key value timeout feature, to remove a particular field if it is not updated in x amount of time. I would then have the host check the existance of this field to check for DC's. I do wonder if this is highly inefficient, as many users potentially will be playing, so will it be bad to have many timeout values in redis and also many other users polling these fields.
2. I could use the sockets.io on('disconnect', ..) to update the field. However I am not sure if this event will fire if for example a users pc freezes?

Anyway I am open to any other ideas also!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Socket.io have a 'heartbeat' to check connection still alive. Default heartbeat timeout is 15s. You can read more about configuring it in [this wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO). If heartbeat fails (user pc freezes) then socket.io will emit 'disconnect' event.

Answer (score 3):

Socket.io should suffice. You can [configure it to use heartbeats](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO) to ping the socket and check its health. If a user's computer freezes it will, in effect, not be able to respond to these heartbeats, causing it to force a disconnect.

To test this you could set up your Socket.io to use heartbeats, then connect via a browser onn a different computer. While in the browser past into the console an infinite loop. Causing it to simulate a freeze.

Comment: Right, so does that mean, even at the moment, the 'disconnect' event is garunteed to be fired? (even if it it does have to wait 15 seconds / whatever amount of time is configured)